# GEOSException: IllegalArgumentException: point array must contain 0 or >1 elements

Tags: python, geopandas

I am trying to read a shapefile using `geopandas`:

```
import geopandas
green = geopandas.read_file('./shapefiles/unnamed (1)_amber.shp')
```

But it raises the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-29-d9e9517cddc8>", line 1, in <module>
    green = geopandas.read_file('./shapefiles/unnamed (1)_amber.shp')

  File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py", line 259, in _read_file
    return _read_file_fiona(

  File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py", line 360, in _read_file_fiona
    df = GeoDataFrame.from_features(

  File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py", line 635, in from_features
    "geometry": shape(feature["geometry"]) if feature["geometry"] else None

  File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\geo.py", line 98, in shape
    return LineString(ob["coordinates"])

  File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\linestring.py", line 73, in __new__
    geom = shapely.linestrings(coordinates)

  File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\decorators.py", line 77, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\creation.py", line 120, in linestrings
    return lib.linestrings(coords, out=out, **kwargs)

GEOSException: IllegalArgumentException: point array must contain 0 or >1 elements
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: @gene Why? Because it contains a space?

Comment: yes space  and (1)

Comment: `unnamed (1)_amber.shp`  is not a valid filename in Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I couldn't find anything for this error online and thought it would be helpful to share after I found the solution.** The file I was reading consisted of only linestrings. Geopandas does not allow you to read the file if it contains Linestrings that are built on less than three coordinates or points. So in my case, I had to edit my shapefile and remove lines that were drawn with fewer than three points, and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to previous answer by Ali, I was able to fix this error fixing my GeoJSON file before GeoPandas consumes it.

I was also working with LineString Geometries and (in my case this worked with two points only) to draw a line (String) two Points minimum are required, and in my code I was wrongly putting only one.. In the example below, my edge_geolocation list had only one point (long_a, lat_a). "b" coordinates were missing for me...

When fixed adding both points required, error went away.

Example:

```py
import geojson
import geopandas

edge_geolocation = [ (long_a, lat_a) , (long_b, lat_b) ]

edge_feature = geojson.Feature(
            geometry = geojson.LineString(edge_geolocation), 
            properties = { "Property1": Value1, "Property2": "Value2" }
            )

# Save GeoJSON to file, e.g: "geo_edges.json"

Now you can read it from geopandas:

geo_data_frame_edges = geopandas.read_file('geo_edges.json')
```

More info about Geometries and GeoJSON: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for this hint about single-point LineStrings. I go through dozens of shapefiles, and some of them have this issue, so I came up with a way to fix them automatically by removing single-point LineStrings in MultiLineStrings as follows. The minimum number of points can be edited.

```
        try:
            net = gpd.read_file(in_shp)
        #If one of the records has single-point LineStrings, remove these individual LineStrings and re-read
        except shapely.errors.GEOSException: #If one of the records has invalid geometry that prevents reading
            #Path to fixed shapefile
            out_fixed = "{0}_fixed{1}".format(os.path.splitext(in_shp)[0],
                                                  os.path.splitext(in_shp)[1])
            minN = 1

            #Open problematic shapefile
            with fiona.open(in_shp) as input:
                #Create new fixed shapefile
                with fiona.open(out_fixed, 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile',
                                input.schema.copy(), input.crs) as output:
                    #Iterate through features
                    for elem in input:
                        if elem['geometry'] is not None:
                            if elem['geometry'].type == 'MultiLineString':
                                #Remove single-point LineStrings
                                out_coords = [l for l in elem['geometry'].coordinates if len(l) >=  minN]
                                if len(out_coords) > 0:
                                    out_type = 'MultiLineString'
                                else:
                                    out_type = 'LineString'
                                out_elem=  {
                                    'geometry': {'type':out_type,
                                                 'coordinates': out_coords
                                                 },
                                    'properties': elem.properties
                                }
                                output.write(out_elem)

                            elif elem['geometry'].type == 'LineString':
                                if len(elem['geometry'].coordinates) >=  minN:
                                    output.write(elem)
```